# get and set individual width elements

Tags: jquery

Since IE7 doesnt support CSS width:auto; width:100%; or width:inherit; on span tags i need to get and set this width with jQuery.

So how can i set span class="center_bg" to the same width as its nearest span class="text"

I tried the code below, but it applys the same width on every  span class="center_bg" element on every loop thru.

```
jQuery('.ul li span.menu_text').each(function(i) {
   var spanWidth = jQuery(this).width();
   jQuery("span.center_bg").width(spanWidth);
})

<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="left_bg"></span>
      <span class="right_bg"></span>
      <span class="center_bg"></span>
      <span class="text"></span>
    <a/>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a>
     <span class="left_bg"></span>
     <span class="right_bg"></span>
     <span class="center_bg"></span>
     <span class="text"></span>
   <a/>
 </li> 
</ul
```

Comment: What is the CSS for the `span`s?  No browser should support `width` settings for inline elements. That's not a IE7 specific problem, but by design - you'd have to use block or inline-block elements

Comment: Use display block on the spans and float them left. Or change them for div's. +1 Pekka's comment. -1 your approach.

Comment: Do you have an image of how you want this to look? Your approach is the greater problem here.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `span` element is by default
   `display:inline` element.
2. `display:inline` element by
   definition has no dedicated box - it
   is rather collection of individual
   glyph boxes able to wrap on multiple
   lines. Therefore width and height is undefined for inlines.

Try to define this and it should work:

```
.ul li span { display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: I don't think IE7 supports display:inline-block;